# JMeter Postprocessor

Tags: javascript, apache, post, jmeter

Поставлена задача: реализовать сценарий тестирования для добавления объявлений на сайт [olx](http://olx.ua/).

Эту задачу через Recorder я реализовал, в итоге имею этот .jmx тест.
А вот со второй частью задачи проблема: требуется проанализировать post запрос во время добавления объявления с помощью `BSF postprocessor`.
Тут у меня несколько вопросов, ибо с `jmeter` знаком недавно, и слабо понимаю некоторые тонкости.

1. Мне нужно добавить `BSF postprocessor` к `http request`, который будет соответственно относится к странице, когда я уже добавил объявление? Или же мне нужно добавлять цикл в `Thread Group`, и уже туда `BSF postprocessor`?
2. Как получить какое-то поле? Нужно добавить `BSF postprocessor`, `Debug`, `TreeResult` как я понял. А дальше нужно соорудить в этом процессоре скрипт, который будет использовать такие функции как `getResponseData` и put?
   Может кто максимально разжевать эти вопросы или создать таковой тест?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По первому вопросу. `Postprocessor` добавляется к `Sampler`, как дочерний компонент. В Вашем случае у компонента `HTTP Request`, соответствующего запросу добавления объявления на сайт, должен появится дочерний компонент `BSF postprocessor`.

По извлечению данных из страницы с результатами запроса на добавление объявления. В зависимости от типа ответа рекомендуются различные способы.

Предположим, после добавления всегда возвращается ответ с кодом 200 (ОК) и неким текстом - отчёт об успешности добавления объявления на страницу: `Объявление успешно добавлено` или `Не удалось добавить объявление ...`.

Например, ответ является html-документом, где html разметка удобно разбита по строкам, теги снабжены уникальными идентификаторами (id, class) или простой JSON-ответ. И задача - извлечь содержимое одного из тегов. Тогда удобно использовать Regular Expression Etractor - быстро и просто поместить нужное поле в переменную JMeter.

Если ответ является валидным xhtml-документом (отрытые теги закрываются как надо) и его сложно разобрать с помощью регулярных выражений или Xml-документом, то используйте XPath Extractor - вариант чуть медленнее и чуть сложнее, для XML - оптимальный вариант.

Если ответ не является валидным xhtml-документом, а является html-документом, удобно использовать JQuery или CSS-секлеторы, с помощью `JQuery/CSS Extractor`. Предполагаю, что `JQuery/CSS Extractor` медленнее, чем `XPath` и `RegExp`. Но `JQuery/CSS` удобнее и читаемее, чем `XPath` и `RegExp`.

Если ответ никак не разобрать стандартными компонентами, или ответ приходит в Json со сложной структурой или каком-то ином формате, то используйте программный разбор ответа. Тут пригодятся скрипты на BeanShell, Javascript, Groovy, ... или написание собственных плагинов на Java.

Вы верно сказали, для получения тела ответа в BeanShell-скрипте можно использовать `prev.getResponseDataAsString()` или аналог,
а для записи значения в переменную использовать `vars.put(переменная, значение)`.

И судя по Вашим вопросам, Вы читаете третью главу книги JMeter 2.9: https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/9781782165842_Chapter_03.pdf. Вы на верном пути.